# Calling inner class method from outer class while using same instance

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, scope

Im trying to create a Timer class that changes a boolean when the time expires, however I am struggling finding a way to keep the same 'instance' of the Light class (since Im going to have more than one) I doubt static classes and methods are the answer since I have about 5 lights in total

Here's the code, I have included the method I'm trying to call from the thread inside the actual Light class for reference.

```
    import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Light extends RoomObject{
    //Constructors
    public Light(String n, String r, boolean s){
        super(s, r, n);
    }

    //Class methods

    public String toString(){
        return "Light|" + super.getName() + "|" + super.toString() + "|";
    }

    public void setState(boolean s){
        super.setState(s);
    }
}

class TimedLight extends TimerTask{

    public void run() {

    }
}
```

NB. I am trying to call the setState method from the thread

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
class TimedLight  extends TimerTask{
Light light ;
TimedLight (Light light){
this.light = light;
}
 public void run() {
 light.setState(..);

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `TimedLight` is *not enclosed in Light class* as the error says. For referring to Light you need reference to it and for that you can pass it in the constructor.

```
public TimedLight(Light light){
   light.setState(..);
}
```

`TimedLight` is on *same level* as `Light` and *not a nested class*. So you dont have access to instance of Light in TimedLight.